# How to pass environment variables with FreeBSD service command?

Tags: freebsd, service, environment-variables, rc.d

The rc.subr `${name}_env` specifies this for setting environment variable:

```
${name}_env   A list of environment variables to run command
              with.  This will be passed as arguments to
              env(1) utility.
```

So I tried using it like these methods, via my rc.conf for my daemon named `/etc/rc.d/mydaemon`.

in `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
mydaemon_env="MYD_ROOT"
```

This give error on starting:

```
# root @ rahul in /etc/rc.d [10:52:49]
$ service mydaemon onestart
Starting mydaemon.
env: MYD_ROOT: No such file or directory
/etc/rc.d/mydaemon: WARNING: failed to start mydaemon
```

Could someone help out on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be in format `NAME=VALUE`.

```
mydaemon_env="MYD_ROOT=value"
```

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to make `service` pick up the environment variable from the shell where it was invoked?

Answer (score 0):

A new flag has recently been added to the `service` command. With the `-E` flag, it is now possible to set the environment variables when starting a daemon with the `service` command. The new flag will be available in FreeBSD 14.0 and later. As of 2023-09-04, it has not been merged back into older stable branches.

Some references:

- The commit introducing the `-E` flag: https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/usr.sbin/service/service.sh?id=194e059bb80334e6f4f791a186015b20d7f6f4b8